# Find when Oracle 10g table was last populated

Tags: oracle-10g

I am working on an Oracle 10g database which is being populated periodically with data from network nodes. 
What Oracle table can I query to to get the time at which myTableOfInterest was last populated?

I have already searched and tried:
select max(ORA_ROWSCN), scn_to_timestamp(max(ORA_ROWSCN)) from myTableName;
Unfortunately this select results in no rows being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the TIMESTAMP column of the ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2097.htm

Also, keep in mind this part:

> Note: These views are populated only for tables with the MONITORING
>   attribute. They are intended for statistics collection over a long
>   period of time. For performance reasons, the Oracle Database does not
>   populate these views immediately when the actual modifications occur.
>   Run the FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO procedure in the DIMS_STATS
>   PL/SQL package to populate these views with the latest information.
>   The ANALYZE_ANY system privilege is required to run this procedure.